# Error 1452: Cannot add or update a child row (GOLANG AND MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, go, crud, go-gorm

im a golang intern .I have a problem using foreign keys in gorm. im trying to write a crud operation.im using gorm and when using foreign keys the error : Error 1452: Cannot add or update a child row appears.

```
package migrations

import "gorm.io/gorm"

type Category struct {
   gorm.Model
   ID    uint
   Title string `gorm:"type:varchar(255)"`
   Sort  int
}
```

```
package migrations

import "gorm.io/gorm"

type Contents struct {
   gorm.Model
   ID            uint
   CategoryModel Category `gorm:"foreignKey:cat_id"`
   CatId         uint
   Title         string `gorm:"type:varchar(255)"`
   Content       string `gorm:"content,type:varchar(255)"`
}
```

and i got this error :

> 2022/11/23 14:31:33 /home/channelead/Documents/blog-service-go/internal/activities/blog/Contents/action.go:26 Error 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>
> (`service-blog-go`.`contents`, CONSTRAINT `fk_contents_category_model` FOREIGN KEY (`cat_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`))
> [3.247ms] [rows:0] INSERT INTO `contents` (`created_at`,`updated_at`,`deleted_at`,`cat_id`,`title`,`content`) VALUES ('2022-11-23 14:31:33.972','2022-11-23 14:31:33.972',NULL,0,'khodaya  csacas dg','testing ')

Comment: The error says the code tried to insert `cat_id` 0 which doesn't exist. You didn't post the code that inserts those objects but something's wrong at `action.go` , line 26

Comment: Are you trying to insert a new category and content objects at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

Please notice the insert query. You are giving `0` as `cat_id` which reference the ID of `Category` table. But there is no entry with `0` ID in `Category` table. Another important fact is you don’t need `ID` explicitly if you use `gorm.Model` because it has a `ID` field inside. And CategoryModel field should be renamed to Category. These are gorm default but you can configure these things. Please read the [documentation](https://gorm.io/docs/belongs_to.html). Here is the working code [GITHUB LINK](https://github.com/Shahriar-Sazid/go-random-test/blob/master/storage/gorm3.go). You can clone the repo and run.

```
package storage

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "gorm.io/driver/sqlite"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "gorm.io/gorm/logger"
)

type Category struct {
    gorm.Model
    Title string `gorm:"type:varchar(255)"`
    Sort  int
}

type Contents struct {
    gorm.Model
    Category   Category
    CategoryID uint
    Title      string `gorm:"type:varchar(255)"`
    Content    string `gorm:"type:varchar(255)"`
}

func GormTest3() {
    db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("gorm.db"), &gorm.Config{
        Logger: logger.Default.LogMode(logger.Info),
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("could not open database")
    }
    err = db.AutoMigrate(&Contents{}, &Category{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("could not migrate database")
    }
    createTestData3(db)
    fetchData3(db)
}

func createTestData3(db *gorm.DB) {
    category := Category{
        Title: "ABC",
        Sort:  1,
    }
    err := db.Create(&category).Error
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("failed to create user data")
    }

    content := Contents{
        CategoryID: category.ID,
        Title:      "Good Content Title",
        Content:    "Good Content",
    }

    err = db.Create(&content).Error
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("failed to create user data")
    }
}

func fetchData3(db *gorm.DB) {
    var cts []Contents
    if err := db.Find(&cts).Error; err != nil {
        fmt.Println("failed to load post")
    }
    fmt.Println(cts)
}
```

Ref: [Gorm Has One](https://gorm.io/docs/has_one.html)

Comment: can you please help me how to solve the problem

Comment: okay. I will give a working code with this within tomorrow.